# How to go to a folder programmatically?

Tags: wanderlust

`wl-summary-goto-folder` (keybinding <kbd>g</kbd> in [Summary mode](http://www.gohome.org/wl/doc/wl_35.html#SEC76)), permits to jump to a folder whose name is entered interactively.

What I'd like is to pass it the folder name by argument, in order to call it at emacs startup time, with something like

```
emacsclient -c --eval "(wl-folder-goto-folder 'folder_name)"
```

Is there a way I can do that ?

Comment: I use this `(wl-summary-goto-folder-subr "%inbox" nil nil nil t)` or `(wl-summary-goto-folder-subr "%INBOX.Sent" nil nil nil t)`, but I also have some functions that check to see whether `wl` has been initialized and I toggle the plug on at the beginning to download any new mail and then I turn the plug off when I'm done.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of it - why not make it an answer ? A variation on it works for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [lawlist comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30386/how-to-go-to-a-folder-programmatically?noredirect=1#comment46780_30386), the answer is to call the internal function `wl-summary-goto-folder-subr` with the right parameters.

What ends up working for me is :

```
emacsclient -c --eval "(wl-summary-goto-folder-subr '\".INBOX\" t nil nil t)"
```

The last `t` is the `INTERACTIVE` parameter and without it, it "seems to do nothing" (someone more knowledgeable at elisp please explain). The first `t` is the `SCAN-TYPE` parameter, and prevents a prompt (`Range (update):`) at start time. No, I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: and for the sake of completeness, that gives `awful.client.run_or_raise('emacsclient -c --eval "(wl-summary-goto-folder-subr \\\".Inbox\\\" t nil nil t)"', function(c) return awful.rules.match(c, {name = "Summary:%.Inbox"} ) end)` in the awesome config.

Comment: The code contemplates the following `scan-type` arguents:  `nil`; `'all`; `'no-sync`; `'rescan`; `'force-update`; `'update`.  The usage of `t` for `scan-type` has the effect of `'no-sync`.  The code does not recognize `t` when determining whether to execute `wl-summary-sync`, `wl-summary-rescan` or `wl-summary-sync-force-update`.  The `interactive` argument has a bearing on scoring and displaying the buffer with a possible recenter command (rather than just working on the summary buffer behind the scenes).